# Why is OpenSea (Wyvern) using proxy registry?

Tags: opensea

From what I see, when someone tries to sell something on OpenSea, this is the process:

1. The user creates a proxy registry for his token.
2. The user approves the proxy registry to access his token.
3. The user lists his item and signs a message to allow the buyer to buy later using that signed message.

Now my question is: Why do we need the proxy registry? What exactly does it do that cannot be done without it?

I have  tried to read the Wyvern whitepaper, source code, OpenSea help center and all the docs, all the blogs posts published by both org's, and didn't find an answer.

Comment: This also got me curious. Still researching about it.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSea creates a shadow account for all users in order to provide zero-fee listing and minting. The proxy registry supports this feature in that it marries your shadow account to your Ethereum wallet address.